# NSUserDefaults and high score not working?

Tags: save, nsuserdefaults

Ok, This all looks completly correct to me, but it's working sometimes, and not working sometimes. Is there a better way of doing this or am I missing something? Just trying to save High score to NSUserDefaults!

```
-(void)updateScore
{
NSString * currentScore = _scoreLabel.string;
NSLog(@"Current Score, %@", _scoreLabel.string);

NSString * newHighScore = _highScoreLabel.string;
NSLog(@"High Score, %@", _highScoreLabel.string);

if (currentScore > newHighScore) {

    NSLog(@"updating high score!");
    _highScoreLabel.string = currentScore;
    NSUserDefaults *scoreDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [scoreDefaults setObject:_highScoreLabel.string forKey:@"high_Score"];
    [scoreDefaults synchronize];
}

// string for key.
NSLog(@"Saved High Score, %@",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"high_Score"]);

}
```

Here is the log output.

```
// Worked ok here.
2014-04-04 13:58:46.921 [2378:60b] game over
2014-04-04 13:58:46.923 [2378:60b] Current Score, 5
2014-04-04 13:58:46.924 [2378:60b] High Score, 4
2014-04-04 13:58:46.925 [2378:60b] updating high score!
2014-04-04 13:58:46.929 [2378:60b] Saved High Score, 5

// Worked ok here. Did not update score because it was less than high score.
2014-04-04 13:59:01.321 [2378:60b] game over
2014-04-04 13:59:01.323 [2378:60b] Current Score, 1
2014-04-04 13:59:01.325 [2378:60b] High Score, 5
2014-04-04 13:59:01.326 [2378:60b] Saved High Score, 5

// Did NOT WORK, current score was higher than saved high score.
2014-04-04 13:59:22.087 [2378:60b] game over
2014-04-04 13:59:22.089 [2378:60b] Current Score, 6
2014-04-04 13:59:22.092 [2378:60b] High Score, 5
2014-04-04 13:59:22.093 [2378:60b] Saved High Score, 5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is unrelated to `NSUserDefaults`.

```
if (currentScore > newHighScore) ...
```

compares the *pointers* to the Objective-C objects.
You want to compare the integer values:

```
if ([currentScore integerValue] > [newHighScore integerValue]) ...
```

Comment: That seemed to do it, thank you so much! Was driving me crazy!